# Getting error when trying to inject 'ui.router'

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to use the `$stateProvider` in Angular to load in partial modules on a certain view. However I can't get past the first step, which is injecting `'ui.router'`

```
var app = angular.module('app-training', ['ui.router']);
```

http://tinyurl.com/m5hsfr8

**Failed to instantiate module portalExchange due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]**

Comment: Are you including the script that defines the `ui.router` module?

Comment: Ugh, sigh yeah didn't realize it was separated into a different script, but should have since ngRoute is the same way. Found it here: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js want to post the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the ui.router file to your index.html after the AngularJS library. In the last versions of angular the Google team separated the ng-router to a separate module to alow users choose between ng-router and ui-router. I do believe that in the next releases the ui.router will be default.